# Solve $\frac{x^2}{16}=\frac{k+1}{k-1}$ over the integers?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

$$\frac{x^2}{16}=\frac{k+1}{k-1}$$

If both $k$ and $x$ are restricted to the integers. Is there then any solution to this equation?

What would be an elegant way to prove it?

Comment: First things first; why ask for an elegant way to prove it when you haven't demonstrated any knowledge as to how to prove it at all!

Comment: So far the solutions involve checking a subset of possible $k$. Is there a proof possible without having to check subsets?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$
x^2 = 16 \dfrac{k+1}{k-1}
$$
implies
$$
k-1 \ \Big | \ 16(k+1)
$$
we already know $k-1 \Big |16(k-1) $. Therefore
$$
k-1 \ \Big | \ 32
$$
So $k-1$ can be
$$
1,2,4,8,16,32,-1,-2,-4,-8,-16,-32
$$
trying them will give you
$$
(x,k) = (0,-1)
$$

Comment: What is the meaning of the vertical line symbol?

Comment: $a \ \big |  \ b$ means $a$ divides $b$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\frac{x^2}{16}=\frac{k+1}{k-1}\to x^2=16+\frac{32}{k-1}
$$
Obviously, $k-1$ should be divisor of $32$. Which leads us to set:
$$
k=\{-31,-15,-7,-3,-1,0,2,3,5,9,17,33\}
$$
At the same time, whole expression $16+\frac{32}{k-1}$ should be nonnegative, thus $k\ne 0.$
To shrink number of possible $k$'s we can also exploit that $16$ itself is a square, closest to it is $9$, thus absolute value of $\frac{32}{k-1}$ should be not less than $7$, hence big positive or negative $k$'s are unacceptible.
$$
k=\{-3,-1,2,3,5\}
$$
It is easy to check then that only $k=-1;\quad x^2=x=0$ is a solution.